# Не удаётся "Достучаться" до объекта JSON

Tags: java, json

Есть JSON код:

```
{
  "city": {
    "country": "RU",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 37.6156,
      "lat": 55.7522
    },
    "sunrise": 1589332872,
    "timezone": 10800,
    "sunset": 1589391041,
    "name": "Moscow",
    "id": 524901,
    "population": 1000000
  },
  "cnt": 1,
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1589392800,
      "dt_txt": "2020-05-13 18:00:00",
      "weather": [
        {
          "icon": "04n",
          "description": "broken clouds",
          "main": "Clouds",
          "id": 803
        }
      ],
      "main": {
        "temp": 9.82,
        "temp_min": 9.45,
        "grnd_level": 997,
        "temp_kf": 0.37,
        "humidity": 48,
        "pressure": 1012,
        "sea_level": 1013,
        "feels_like": 4.69,
        "temp_max": 9.82
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 77
      },
      "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
      },
      "wind": {
        "deg": 242,
        "speed": 4.35
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Как достучаться до объекта "list.main.temp"
Я пробовал сделать это с помощью .getJSONObject("list")
Но не получилось.
При этом к объекту city.country или cnt работает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример того, как парсить `json` средствами `org.json`:

```
String json = "";
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray jsonList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");
JSONObject jsonItem = jsonList.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject jsonMain = jsonItem.getJSONObject("main");
String temp = jsonMain.getString("temp");
```

Пример того, как парсить `json` с помощью библиотеки `Gson`:

```
Example example = Gson().fromJson(json, Example.class);
Float temp = example.list.get(0).main.temp;
```

POJO классы:

```
class Example {
    @SerializedName("city")
    public City city;
    @SerializedName("cnt")
    public Integer cnt;
    @SerializedName("cod")
    public String cod;
    @SerializedName("message")
    public Integer message;
    @SerializedName("list")
    public List<WList> list = null;
}

class City {
    @SerializedName("country")
    public String country;
    @SerializedName("coord")
    public Coord coord;
    @SerializedName("sunrise")
    public Integer sunrise;
    @SerializedName("timezone")
    public Integer timezone;
    @SerializedName("sunset")
    public Integer sunset;
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("id")
    public Integer id;
    @SerializedName("population")
    public Integer population;
}

class Clouds {
    @SerializedName("all")
    public Integer all;
}

class Coord {
    @SerializedName("lon")
    public Float lon;
    @SerializedName("lat")
    public Float lat;
}

class WList {
    @SerializedName("dt")
    public Integer dt;
    @SerializedName("dt_txt")
    public String dtTxt;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    public java.util.List<Weather> weather = null;
    @SerializedName("main")
    public Main main;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    public Clouds clouds;
    @SerializedName("sys")
    public Sys sys;
    @SerializedName("wind")
    public Wind wind;
}

class Main {
    @SerializedName("temp")
    public Float temp;
    @SerializedName("temp_min")
    public Float tempMin;
    @SerializedName("grnd_level")
    public Integer grndLevel;
    @SerializedName("temp_kf")
    public Float tempKf;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    public Integer humidity;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    public Integer pressure;
    @SerializedName("sea_level")
    public Integer seaLevel;
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    public Float feelsLike;
    @SerializedName("temp_max")
    public Float tempMax;
}

class Sys {
    @SerializedName("pod")
    public String pod;
}

class Weather {
    @SerializedName("icon")
    public String icon;
    @SerializedName("description")
    public String description;
    @SerializedName("main")
    public String main;
    @SerializedName("id")
    public Integer id;
}

class Wind {
    @SerializedName("deg")
    public Integer deg;
    @SerializedName("speed")
    public Float speed;
}
```

Comment: Вот так вот, приходят, спрашивают. Получают ответ и ни тебе спасибо, ничего в ответ) Ну да, тут же роботы сидят, отвечают)

Comment: Скажите спасибо, что автор вопрос не удалил, как получил ответ :) У меня такое часто случалось.

Comment: @tym32167 Ахах) Это вдвойне обиднее будет)

Comment: А смысл спасибо говорить если никакой пользы я не извлёк?

Comment: @SuperMyke ну так и скажите, что я вам не помог, будем искать другие варианты. А почему собственно это решение вам не принесло пользы? Решение рабочее 100%

Comment: @SuperMyke Дополнил ответ. Возможно это тот вариант, на который вы рассчитывали изначально